# Powershell - Check if all elements of ForEach are equal to something

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I need to look in Windows registry and get a specific value out of a list of subkeys.
What I want is to have a return output as "ok" only when all values properties in these subkeys are equal to "2".

If I write something like this:

```
$regkey = "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces"
Get-ChildItem $regkey |
foreach { $NetbiosOptions_Value = (Get-ItemProperty "$regkey\$($_.pschildname)").NetbiosOptions }
if ($NetbiosOptions_Value -eq 2) {
write-output "ok"}
else{
}
```

obviously gives me "OK" with just one of the values being equal to "2" but what I want is to have "OK" only when all values are equals to "2"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `if` statement inside the loop and then invert it - if a value is *not* `2`, we want to *prevent* the script from saying `"ok"` at the end:

```
$foundNonMatching = $false
$regkey = "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces"
Get-ChildItem $regkey |ForEach-Object { 
    $NetbiosOptions_Value = (Get-ItemProperty "$regkey\$($_.pschildname)").NetbiosOptions
    if($NetbiosOptions_Value -ne 2){
        $foundNonMatching = $true
    }
}

if(-not $foundNonMatching){
  "ok"
}
else{
  "No good, found a wrong one!"
}
```